# TFS agent pool roles not able to add specific user

Tags: build-agent

On our on-premise TFS 2017 update 2 I want to add an extra user to the Agent Pool role as an administrator. For some reason I can not find all users in the domain. 
In the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SmPl.png) you can see that the user TFSBuild was added previously, but now when when searching or it it can not be found. I know for certain that this user still exists because in other place (e.g. add it to a a project group) I can add it. Also I'm able to add other users so the permissions to add users to the administrator role are OK.

I noted that I can add the user to the 'Project Collection Build Administrator group' but I still cannot add it to the Agent Pools or it doesn't show up in the 'filter users and groups' of the collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you could try to add that specific user to another agent pool. This will narrow down if the issue is related to the agent pool.

It maybe  an Identity Synchronization issue, you could  check this [blog](http://blogs.msmvps.com/vstsblog/2011/02/17/force-tfs-to-sync-with-active-directory/) which discusses how to do a force sync.

Besides, you could also directly add group instead of a user on the agent pool. The users in the group will also gained the roles. And based on the roles, they will govern what operations they can perform on an agent pool.

So as a workaround, you could add a group which only included this user instead of this user, then double check if the user has properly permission.

Comment: Seemed to be a Synchonization issue. Now I'm able to add the user to the pool. The strange thing is however that in other places in TFS I was able to add the user already.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is add the user or AD-group to a team project TFS group as member. For example as a reader. Then the synchronization is done by TFS and you will be able to resolve and add the role member in the agent pool after a few minutes.